# Weird dollar sign in global variables

Tags: jenkins

I want to define a global variable in jenkins which contains `USERNAME` environment variable of my computer.

[image]

[image]

Suppose my `USERNAME` is `myName`. When I execute the following build, the values of `ttt` are all `C:\Users\myName$\.jenkins`.

[image]

I don't know why there's a dollar sign (`$`) at the end of `myName`. I want to get rid of it. The dollar sign makes me not able to change to `C:\Users\myName\.jenkins` directory by running `cd %ttt%` command.

Is there something wrong with the way I define `ttt`? Or is this a bug of jenkins?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour with Jenkins ver. 1.656 and the latest stable ver. 2.32.2. Even if I use `%USERNAME%` in the Windows batch build step directly.

Comment: Another finding: If I run `set` in the batch step it shows `USERNAME=...$` and `ttt=...$\ `, as well. All other env vars are displayed as expected.